# What are the consequences of using a relay that seems to cause the fuel pump to be on all the time?

Tags: electrical, fuel-system, golf, fuel-pump

The fuel pump relay in my Mk1 Golf (1.8lt, injected) died. To get home I swapped it with the Load Reduction relay. The car worked fine, except that now when I turn the key to Accessories the fuel pump fires up straight away - the fuel pumps run whether the engine is on or not.

Is this dangerous? Are there any consequences? (Is this even the way it is meant to be?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not meant to be like this - some are designed to pressurise on opening drivers door others as you put the ignition on.

So that “repair” got you home - now get the correct relay and fit it so that the correct functionality is there.

If the pump runs all the time it could fail sooner or perhaps cause a flat battery or even a leak...